# Does this SASS structure affect React app/component loadtime/performance?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm working on my first production-ready React application, and I'm using SASS as a pre-processor for my CSS. One huge benefit I find when styling my React components is being able to break my CSS into separate modules and import the specific modules needed into the corresponding React component.

The more my application grows, the harder it has become to quickly find and update the correct CSS I need while developing. Which leads to my question...

I'm thinking of implementing the following styling, and I'm not sure if it will have any effect on the performance of my app and components:

`1 - Continue to separate all CSS into SASS modules
2 - Import all of those modules into a single app.scss file
3 - Import that single app.scss file into all of the components that need styling`

This will let me browse a single place - app.scss - for the specific css module I need, and then quickly tell me where I need to go in my app directory to access that file. I see this being beneficial as I could write brief comments in the app.scss about each of the individual modules. That way as the app scales, I'll have documentation about what each css module accomplishes and what components those css modules correspond to.

Thus, my question is will this style of loading so many modules into a single css file and then loading that single css file into each component that needs styling slow down my app/component load time/performance?

Comment: How have you been using your class names? Are they unique to each style or are they page specific?